# UINavigationViewController setViewControllers not setting correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am having an issue where calling `setViewControllers` does not set my array of view controllers to my navigation view controller. I *am* doing this in a block, so I'm not sure if it's a UI issue (but I have tried solving this by setting my view controllers in the main queue).

```
[self thisIsABlock:^(){
        UIViewController3 *viewController3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HeyHey"];
        // viewController3 is not nil

        NSMutableArray *array1 = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
        // array1 contains [viewController1, viewController2]

        [array1 addObject:viewController3];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:array1 animated:NO];
        // Now array1 contains [viewController1, viewController2, viewController3] 

        NSMutableArray *array2 = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
        // array2 only contains [viewController1, viewController2]
}];
```

This block of code is an abstraction of what I'm doing in my codebase. I may be missing some crucial code that is causing this issue but I hope that someone has encountered this problem before and knows what the problem is. Thanks!

// EDIT 1: I am calling this at `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

When I open the app from background to foreground, my code works.

Comment: Where else are you calling this block in other words Are you expecting it to work when called from other places? If so where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Above code is correct, but you can provide valid data like this,

```
YourViewController *viewController3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryBoardViewControllerIdentifer"];
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've made sure to check the `viewController3` object and see if it's valid and not `nil`. I've left a comment in the example code in my question.